# Microstack/Openstack VMs access on public/physical network

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon, microstack

I'm new to openstack tech. need suggestions to implement. Apology if I have used an non tech. language as networks are not my core domain.

**Problem:**

I'm not able to access my vm's out of virtual microstack network on my physical network even after adding floating IPs; On ping I get packet filtered.

Trying to attach my VLAN created on cisco switch so all vms can take address or IPs from that vlan.

- How can i configure vlan created on switch so I can connect VMs on public network; Is it possible via Horizon portal using network type VLAN, GRE if so kindly guide me to add correct configurations
- Any other suggestion or way so I can access my VMs on public network too.

**What I have achieved up till now :**

- deployment of openstack via microstack
- Adding compute nodes
- accessing internet on VMs
- Inter VM communication on same network
- connection out side virtual network using **flat** network types by creating bridge on same node

Thanks in advance !

Comment: An internet search for [connect microstack to network](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=connect+microstack+to+network) gives you a few options. To attach it to a VLAN, either attach the host to a VLAN port in the switch, or attach the host to a trunk line and create a VLAN interface on the host. You could provide a bit more info about your setup, too. How is the Microstack host networked right now. How is Microstack's external network conncted. From where to where do you ping, and what exactly is the error message.

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks for the reply. We have a Cisco switch SG350-28P and we are looking forward to configure it as per our requirement. Currently I'm setting VLAN for microstack what is the best config for VLAN e.g. we make a dhcp server or static IP pool that will fit with microstack. --- Second error that I was getting was with Flat external network type and we been getting `icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered` on accessing from other machines on same network.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an article that presents an approach for implementing MicroStack Single Node with connectivity between VMs and physical network. Please have a look and see if it works for you.

This is the link to the article:

https://connection.rnascimento.com/2021/03/08/openstack-single-node-microstack/

Comment: Nice article but that will create bridge on single node we are looking forward for production scale deployment. For like 30 physical machines. For now main problem is external network configuration with physical network.

Comment: I cant get access to the UI to follow this guide. how can I create bridge between my network to this openstack network?

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying on a virtual or physical network, is you explain your deployment infrastructure that would make lots simple to point out the connectivity solution

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.